# Drupal_render Profile 2 Forms

Tags: users

The main Profile can be printed in a basic PHP page using:

```
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')));
print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));
```

but how can I specify a Profile 2 profile to be printed instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print out the the profile2 profile Programmatically, you can do the following:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'profile2_page', 'profile2_page'); // Include profile2_page module
global $user; // Current user.
$profile2 = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'profile2_machine_name'); 
$entity_form = entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile2, 'edit'); // Or 'add'
print drupal_render($entity_form);
```

This should allow you to edit a Profile2 fields from the current logged in user. For registration I'm not sure how to print that other than redirect the user to the specific Registration Path from the [Profile2 Registration Path](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath), but for Logging in you can use the default form like in my question:

```
 print(drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login_block')));
```

P.S: Remember to clear you cache.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty simple, since profile 2 makes good use of the entity api module.

```
$profile = profile2_load($pid);
print $profile->view(); // prints the rendered profile.
```

To get the profile form

```
print render(entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile));
```

Comment: I tried printing the form for one of the profiles:
    global $user;
    $profile = profile2_load($user->uid);
    print render(entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile));
The site simply gave me an Error and showed:
"The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Comment: @JasonB You have to check the logs to find out what's wrong. Most likely an exception in the entity module, could happen if $profile isn't a profile but a null value like FALSE or NULL

Comment: I found the error. I needed to load the profile2_page module and clear my cache: module_load_include('inc', 'profile2_page', 'profile2_page');

Comment: be aware that profile2_page module must be enabled